# AxiosError Network Error while sending email and password from Expo App to Mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react-native, expo

**Description:**
I am trying to create an Expo app with a login and signup page. I have stored some data in my MySQL database.

Database Check: [Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2O5l.png)

I can successfully send data from Postman to the MySQL database using Node.js. However, when I attempt to send data from my Expo app to the database through an API, I encounter the following error: `AxiosError: Network Error`.

**API for Login:**

```js
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const checkEmailSql = `select * from users WHERE email = ?`;

  connection.query(checkEmailSql, [email], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).json('Error querying the database');
    } else {
      if (results.length === 0) {
        res.status(404).json('Email not found');
      } else {
        const user = results[0];
        if (password === user.password) {
          res.status(200).json('Login successful');
        } else {
          res.status(401).json('Incorrect password');
        }
      }
    }
  });
});




Server Configuration:
const port = 3000;
const ipAddress = '0.0.0.0';

Function to Login:
const handleLogin = async () => {
  try {
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    const response = await axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:3000/login', { email, password });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const { userExists, passwordMatches } = response.data;

      if (userExists && passwordMatches) {
        setErrorMessage('');
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      } else if (!userExists) {
        setErrorMessage('User not found');
      } else {
        setErrorMessage('Invalid password');
      }
    } else {
      setErrorMessage('An error occurred while logging in');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

Postman vs Expo App Screenshots:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frBmE.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN7cn.png) => please copy the links and open in browser for screenshots

I don't believe the issue is with the APIs or Axios. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?
```